# Sukthams with khilams from Rigveda?

Tags: vedas, translation-request, rig-veda, book-recommendation

I am deeply interested in receiving any printed Rig-Vedic hymns with khila vaakyams (supplement verses) arranged with swaras (tone for recitation).

---

EDIT:

What are "khila vaakyams"?

FYI:

We have the verses in Rig Veda divided into various sookthams to some of which later supplemented with more verses by section of its authors. These are khila vaakhyams. E.g. In RV Sooktham No. 191 of 10<sup>th</sup> Mandala, we find the verses beginning with the wordings such as 'samgyana mushanavadad samgyanam varoonovadat...'

Comment: What are "khila vakyams"?

Comment: we have the verses in rig veda  divided into various sookthams to some of which later supplemented with more verses by section of its authors.  These are khila vakhyams.      E.g.  RV Sooktham No.191 of 10th Mandalams, we find the verses beginning with the wordings 'samgyana mushanavadad samgyanam varoonovadat .......

Answer (score 2):

I have this book in hardcover:

https://vedah.com/product/rig-veda-mantra-samhita-with-auxialiaries/

Not sure if it is still the same edition, but I bought mine in 1998 or 1999, and it had the full text of all the Khila Suktams with svara marks.