# Can anyone please provide me with a link or pdf of rig veda khilani for reading online.?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, rig-veda, vedic-gods, vedic-rituals

I have been searching rig veda [Khilani or khila](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khilani) (which are later additional hymns to rig veda including shri suktam) for so many days, but I couldn't find it. So can anyone please provide me with the link or pdf or any soft copy of this for reading online.

If possible it will be very helpful if the verses are in all three (sankrit, english, hindi) languages. But sanskrit verse should be there with translation.

Thank you in advance.

Edit.:

My question is fundamentally different from [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15976/20968) question. As that guy is asking for whole rig veda as a hard copy like a book or in printed page but I am asking only for rig veda khilani as a soft copy like a website, link or pdf for download or online reading cz I m in home quarantine after being posted to the positive patients ward for couple of weeks. It's like he is asking for body and I m for soul of a same person, it's same person but the requirements are totally different. Plus I am posting this question after searching in hse for this. If u guys still think both the questions are same than god bless u my friend. Just provide me with a link or pdf of rig veda khila I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sukthams with khilams from Rigveda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15976/sukthams-with-khilams-from-rigveda)

Comment: @Archit nope the guy is asking for whole rig veda n khila hard copy but here I m asking for a link or pdf so that I can read it online.

Comment: Something helpful might be here, although there's no English I guess: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.326386/page/n987/mode/1up?view=theater

Comment: @Vivikta you can post the answer again with the same link, i will accept it. I have just given an answer, otherwise the question might get deleted by community like one of the questions of mine did. Anyways, when you post your ans with the link. I will accept it. Prd..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have to work out with [this one](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.326386/page/n987/mode/1up?view=theater) only.

|| Om Tat Sat ||